# Stream terminal output to android or similar

Tags: gnome-terminal, android, output, streaming

I've been thinking, constantly checking the terminal while waiting for a very long and many times, error prone and attention demanding, processes is a very exhaustive and slightly annoying thing to do, mainly when you are doing something else, or in another room, so, my question is, is there any way to stream the terminal output to an android device or similar? From a programming point of view it seems simple enough, I would be glad to make something of sort, however, I've never tried mobile development, so it would be really nice if there was something available already, unfortunately a Google search didn't reveal me much.

Comment: Can you remember to start your shell session in a `screen` session?  If so, you could make it shared with some other user, ssh in to your box from your 'droid/ithing/whatever and connect to that screen and watch the output....  http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/index.php/HowTo_Share_A_Terminal_Session_Using_Screen

Comment: @ivanivan This is very interesting, it is not the most practical method, of course, but, this is not really a problem, I believe it may solve my problem, I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: Interesting question.  In the old days there was `ttysnoop` that you could use over `ssh`, not sure if that's still available.

Comment: @SatōKatsura Apparently it hasn't been updated in 16 years, however, it seems to still work, on some systems at least. It looks like an amazing tool, and exactly what I was looking for, I'm definitely trying that, thank you!

Comment: `tmux` is the new `screen` with more flexibility.